# HDD Data cables Sata 2 or Sata 3? (Dell Inspiron 580)

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata, dell-inspiron, cable

I want to add an additional [hard drive](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01LNJBA2I/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&psc=1) on my dell Inspiron 580 pc.

My [motherboard](http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/specs-dell-0c2kjt/) only supports **sata 2** hard drives but the one I want to install is **sata 3**.

Should I buy a Sata 2 or 3 **data cable**?

I know sata 3 cables can transfer higher speeds but I don't know if my **motherboard** can support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SATA3.

It will not break anything, and all will work the same.

**[EDIT]**

SATA was designed to be backwards compatible. What this means in your case is that 
you can certainly use a SATA III drive with that motherboard but you'll only get SATA II performance from it, as dictated by the motherboard specs.